# Array with multiple values to Mysql (php)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I think I'm almost there, but I can't seem to get across the line.

I have a form, for which the results are generated as another form in table format, you then confirm submission here. E.g.: search product, select quantity 2 (giving two rows of table, confirm submit).

Submit then pushes these values into an array. The array is inserted into the db with a prepared statement. The values are coming across to my array fine (print_r array to see output), however they're not inserting correctly into the database, with the array values just inserting the first letter of the array value(eg: test will insert t) in just the first row, other values set manually(such as date or status insert correctly).

Can you see where I'm going wrong with the insert? I've tried numerous examples, this appears to be the closest.

```
$date= date("Y-m-d");

$data = array(                                        
'Name' => $_POST['data']['name'],
'Price' => $_POST['data']['price'],
'Something' => $_POST['data']['something'] );

 $stmt = $conn->DB->prepare("INSERT INTO Table (
         Name, Price, Something, Date) 
 VALUES(?, ?, ?, ?)");

 foreach ($_POST['data']['name'] as $k => $order){
   $name = $order['Name'][$k];
   $price = $order['Price'][$k];
   $something = $order['Something'][$k];

   $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $price, $something, $date);
   $stmt->execute();
 }


 echo '<pre>'; print_r($data); echo '</pre>';
```

Example of array output:

```
Array
(
[Name] => Array
    (
        [0] => Joe
        [1] => Blog
        [2] => Joe
        [3] => Phil
    )

[Price] => Array
    (
        [0] => expensive
        [1] => cheap
        [2] => extortionate
        [3] => worthless
    )
[Something] => Array
    (
        [0] => 
        [1] => something
        [2] => something
        [3] => 
    )
)
```

in this example I would expect to insert four rows into the db with joe, expensive,the date and nothing(in the something column) for the first row and so on..

What actually happens is it inserts the four rows, and will put the first letter of the array value in the first row, but nothing in the other rows apart from the date value. eg: j,e, blank and then the date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. If it works I'll update the answer with what was wrong.

```
foreach ($_POST['data']['name'] as $k => $order){
   $name = $data['Name'][$k];
   $price = $data['Price'][$k];
   $something = $data['Something'][$k];

   $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $name, $price, $something, $date);
   $stmt->execute();
 }
```

Comment: I was looking for what you'd changed when I spotted my typo! I've edited the question, that was just an error as I copied the code across to here sorry!

Comment: @Pat what about `$name = $data['Name'][$k];` instead of `$name = $order['Name'][$k];` I changed $data to $order. Is that a typo too?

Comment: apologies, you're correct, changing order to data did the trick. the foreach is looping as intended but I'd pointed it wrong for the array values by the looks of things. I was using the accepted answer here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21557142/array-insert-array-values-to-mysql-table) as a base once I started having issues. Thanks so much!